# random number javascript onclick doesn't work

Tags: javascript, random, onclick, settimeout

I'm trying to use setTimeout.

Without setTimeout my function works,but using setTimeout it stops. Any one knows what I am doing wrong? I want that function works only 3 seconds after click.

```
let d6
document.getElementById("rollButton").onclick = function d6click(){
d6 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
document.getElementById("resultd6").innerHTML = d6;
};
setTimeout(d6click, 3000)
```

Comment: After clicking the button do you want to update the result with a new random number every three seconds? Is that what the timeout is meant to do?

Answer (score 0):

you need the function declared like this -

```
function d6click(){
    let d6 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    document.getElementById("resultd6").innerHTML = d6;
};
document.getElementById("rollButton").onclick = ()=>{
    setTimeout(d6click, 3000)
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the callback, but not actually executing the setTimeout function. When you call it, it will begin the timer so you should call it inside the event block

```
document.getElementById("rollButton").onclick = function d6click(){
    setTimeout(d6timeout, 3000)
};

function d6timeout(){
    let d6 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    document.getElementById("resultd6").innerHTML = d6;
}
```

Comment: How are you calling `timeout`?

Comment: oops forgot to change what’s being called, edited to fix